# Sharepoint 2007 - Querying multiple domains

Tags: active-directory

The existing system (phone book) on the client's SharePoint intranet site is .net application that is integrated with SharePoint site. Now the client wants to change the application to query from multiple domains compared to one domain which is what the existing app is doing.

Is there quick fix, where we can pull data from multiple domains and show it in list or web part?
This will be temporary fix, because the existing .net app might get performance hit if it’s changed to query data from multiple domains.

Any ideas? This is for SharePoint 2007 intranet site.

Comment: Is the .NET app currently reading Sharepoint data? or the .NET app just a link from Sharepoint to a .NET app hosted in the same domain?

Comment: The .net phone book app was directly talking to the active directory through the LDAP query. But the thrid party web part we used gets all the data from sharepoint user profile store, where the user profiles are imported from active directory. I will still not recommend this approach because if there are large number of users hitting this page or you need load large number of records on this web part. It becomes very very slow.

Comment: Yes its a link hosted in the same domain.We are now thinking to change the .net app, so it connects to more than one active directory domain ( as its currently doing now). We were very skeptical about the performance hence did not chnage the .net app, but as the thrid party web part is also not doing great job , we might just modify the .net app. Any suggestions?will this be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

We went with a third party web part: http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5785.

This required:

1. Building import connections to all the active directory domain from where you want to show the user profile.
2. Configuring the web part to pull user profile from user profile store of your sharepoint site.

This does the job but if the users are more than 10,000, it affects the web part performance. Though this was the quick fix we went with.